# Why does this query cause tmp table to be stored on disk even though its size is smaller than tmp_table_size?

Tags: mysql-8.0, percona

I have MySQL server (8.0.29-21 - Percona Server) with:

- `tmp_table_size=67108864`
- `max_heap_table_size=67108864`
- `log_slow_filter="tmp_table_on_disk"`

And in the slow query log, I can see lots of:

```bash
# Time: 2023-07-30T21:26:12.421643Z
# User@Host: root[root] @  [10.42.5.23]  Id: 99902
# Schema:   Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 0.008407  Lock_time: 0.000001  Rows_sent: 4  Rows_examined: 1070  Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 397
# Tmp_tables: 2  Tmp_disk_tables: 1  Tmp_table_sizes: 254839
# InnoDB_trx_id: 0
# Full_scan: Yes  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: Yes  Tmp_table_on_disk: Yes
# Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0
#   InnoDB_IO_r_ops: 0  InnoDB_IO_r_bytes: 0  InnoDB_IO_r_wait: 0.000000
#   InnoDB_rec_lock_wait: 0.000000  InnoDB_queue_wait: 0.000000
#   InnoDB_pages_distinct: 12
SET timestamp=1690752372;
SELECT COALESCE(command,''),COALESCE(state,''),count(*),sum(time)
          FROM information_schema.processlist
          WHERE ID != connection_id()
            AND TIME >= 0
          GROUP BY command,state
          ORDER BY null;
```

This metrics query is executed every 10 seconds by PMM server from percona.

My question is: why is this query causing temporary table/tables on disk when its `Tmp_table_sizes` is 254839 which is way lower than the custom `tmp_table_size=67108864` setting?